# The filters in django rest framework doesn't work with personalized generic view class

Tags: python, list, filter, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I am developing a hierarchical api for the models of my app,  example:

https:  //www.example.com/model/pk/submodel/pk2/subsubmodel/pk3  ...etc

so because of that I have to personalizate the generic view class adding the corresponding method for each action example:(`def list()`, `def retrieve()` ). The problem of that is things like pagination and filtering doesn't work, I have already solved the problem of pagination by adding a few lines of code in the list method but I have not found any way to solve the problem with the filters.

here's an example of my code:

the serializer:

```
class RegionSerializerList(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = Region
         fields = ('id', 'name')
```

The view:

```
class RegionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Region.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegionSerializerList
    pagination_class = PostPageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['name', 'id']

    def list(self, request, pk):
        self.pagination_class = PostPageNumberPagination
        queryset = Region.objects.filter(country=pk)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        #the following 3 lines fix the pagination problem
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = RegionSerializerList(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

the **filters** botom appears in the web but any function works, Neither the order nor the search works, It continues showing all the same data of the list, Using the URL filter (/?search=) doesn't, and neither using the `get_queryset` method.

I'm using `filter_backends` with `SearchFilter`, `OrderingFilter` and the `search_fields` that work perfectly without the personalised method list, but if i used that method doesn't works  I don't know why and how to fix that. :( 
I need the filter to work without having to change the personalized methods on which my api depends

Then I wonder if anyone here knows how to solve this problem and give me a hand, I would appreciate it a lot,  thanks